# How do you run an excel function from within Python?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, plugins

We are using an excel plugin to pull some data from an API. Our excel file contains a column with an entity identifier, and we use an excel formula to pull data for this entity from the internet.

Is it possible to run this from within Python?

I could export my `pd.DataFrame` to csv, open it with excel, append the data I want, and read it back into pandas... but is there a quicker way?

Answer (score -1):

You can import the request and extract data using the Json() method

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'
r = requests.get(url)
json = r.json()
json
```

Then you have the data and just need to include it in your dataframe

Comment: To clarify, I'm not looking to ping a public URL for some data. I have a plugin in excel that is authenticating to a remote server and fetching data - and the API keys/API used by the plugin are not public.